# What is the purpose of ?: and .*? before \K in regular expressions?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a regular expression that matches words with `.` in between them as potential urls but not those with `@` in front of them as they are assumed to be emails.

This is the regex that I have:

```
(?:\@(https?:\/\/)?(\w+(\-*\w+)*\.)[a-zA-Z\.]+[\w+\/?\#?\??\=\%\&\-]+.*?)*\K(https?:\/\/)?(\w+(\-*\w+)*\.)[a-zA-Z\.]+[\w+\/?\#?\??\=\%\&\-]+
```

This is not working for the last occurrence of email perfectly.

For example, for the string

```
twitter.com facebook.com kamur@test.com ksou@uni.edu vimal@gsomething.com balaji@sweets.com john wayne <johnwayne@dc.com> 20,000.00
```

I expect the matches to be `twitter.com` and `facebook.com`.

But it also matches `dc.com`.

Comment: How is it working? How do you expect it to work? Please provide an [MCVE]. Thanks!

Comment: This pattern doesn't make any sense, don't waste your time with it and read tutorials.

Comment: ?: Means non capturing Group, .*? Means non greedy zero or more of any character.

Comment: The matches, you showed, can really mean anything and does not have to be urls. The regex starts correctly with 'https?:'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 4):

In your `(?:\@(https?:\/\/)`, the `?` in `https?:` will match either **http** or **https**. The `?` literally means **0 or 1** of the character `s`. The `:` you refer to in `https?:` is matching a literal `:`, nothing special.

Now, the difference is if your `?:` comes after a ***non***-escaped opening parenthesis, then that means it's a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/5781745).

> Escaped: `\(?:`, **not** a non-capturing group
>   Not-Escaped: `(?:`, **is** a non-capturing group

---

The next portion of your question, what does the `.*?` in `[\w+\/?\#?\??\=\%\&\-]+.*?` refer to?

- `.` will match any character
- `*` is a *quantifier* that will match your `.` <sub>*(any character)*</sub> *0 to unlimited* times
- `*?` makes `*` *non-greedy*. An [internet search](https://www.google.com/search?q=regular+expressions+greedy+vs+non+greedy) will provide you with a lot of information on what a non-greedy match is if you are unaware.